# Pass All Forms in Project To a Function

Tags: c#, winforms, function

I want to let a user select a color scheme and have all my forms change to that color.  so I wanted to do something like this:

```
                  foreach (Form frm in OwnedForms)
        {
            BaseFunctions.ChangeColorScheme(frm);
        }
```

inside that function, i go through each control.  owned forms and Application.OpenForms were two things that other people said to try, but neither worked.  so im not sure what to do.  i tried to use my namespace, but perhaps im missing something.  I went with Namespace.Forms  but Forms isnt an option

Comment: Why not use application conffiguration and use that as a central source of truth. Its very easy to use and you can easily save changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a configuration file for this task. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx

Comment: thanks for all the extra work. never done this before, but its pretty cool.  thanks